# Operaion on Simple Discrete Time Signal , Very Simple Question

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution

I got this simple Discrete time signal question on which i have to perform shifting and multiplication.But I have some Doubt regarding the answer this book shows. Please see the uploaded image.
[image]

Comment: The answer is (possibly) incorrect; the hint is dreadful. The sequence $u[\cdot]$ enjoys the property that it has value $1$ if and only if whatever is between the $[$ and $]$ has value $\geq 0$.  Thus, $u[2-n]$ equals $1$ if and only if $n$ is such that $2-n \geq 0$, that is, $n \leq 2$. So $x[n]u[2-n]$ certainly has value $1$ for $n = 0, 1, 2$ and $0$ for $n > 2$. _How_ the solution-writer figures out that when $n = -1$, $x[-1]$ has value $1$, and so $$x[-1]u[2-(-1)] = x[-1]u[3] = x[-1] = 1$$ is a mystery to me.

Comment: @DilipSarwate : I think solution is incorrect. What is the possible answer sequence according to you? , x(n)u(2-n) = ?

Comment: $$\left\{\cdots \quad x[-1] \quad x[0] \quad x[1] \quad x[2] \quad 0 \cdots\right\} = \left\{\cdots, \quad x[-1] \quad 1 \quad 1 \quad 1 \quad 0 \quad 0 \quad \cdots\right\}$$